# Show data received by Wearable.DataApi when open the app

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am sending data to my Android Wear device from my phone using this code:

```
PutDataRequest putDataRequest = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient,putDataRequest);
```

On my Android Wear device, when the app is open, I use an override method `onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer)` and yes, the data that I receive is shown correctly.

But I need to receive data when my Android Wear app is closed, and show it when I open the app.

Anyone have a clue how to do this?

Thanks.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can receive data in any state. It doesn't matter if your app is open or not.

Just put the following in your Android manifest:

```
<service android:name=".YourService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- listeners receive events that match the action and data filters -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/yourPathPrefix" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and add the following Java code:

```
public class DataWearableListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        super.onDataChanged(dataEvents);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    }
}
```